# AWS Cloudwatch alarm didn't send alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I made an alarm on aws cloudwatch to send me emails whenever an alert is triggered, and last night the alert WAS trigerred and i can see that from the history 
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1iFv.png)

but for some reason there was no email received whatsoever, what could i have done wrong here?
This my alarm configuration:
[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/438FT.png) 
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyu8u.png)

any help or guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified your SNS topic can send emails to your specified email address? If you navigate to your specific SNS topic in the console and view the subscriptions for your topic is the status `Pending confirmation` or `Confirmed`?